# How to install pg gem for ruby 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pg

```
ruby '3.0.2'

gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.4', '>= 6.1.4.1'
gem 'pg', '~> 1.2'
```

`rails s` doesn't work anymore.

```
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': cannot load such file -- 3.0/pg_ext (LoadError)
```

Where I can get the folder '3.0'?

Comment: How about a `bundle install` ?

Comment: If `rails s` "doesn't work anymore", has it worked before? What have you changed from when it worked? What is the exact versions of your `pg` gem? Please also edit your question to add those details. Also, please add the full stack trace.

Comment: With that being said, it appears that the currently released versions of the `pg` gem require one of several possible workarounds on Windows with Ruby 3.0. Please refer to the comments on [issue #365](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/issues/365#issuecomment-758717354) for details.